# Binding Data to DataList

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datalist

I have four separate DataList controls which binds data from different tables.i need to bind all these data to one DataList and sort it by date datafield (which retrieved from database).My issue is it's not possible to join the database tables.Is it possible to bind several datasources to same dataList and sort it by date?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to join the database tables in code via populating some object collection using linq, sort, and binding the resulting collection to the data list.